# Need to autofill rows on google sheet if there is a value in corresponding column

Tags: google-sheets, fill, autofill, array-formulas

Having extensively looked I can't currently find a way to resolve this.

Simply put I need to autofill columns B, C, D with the formula in the cells above, if a value is in column A.

This is because I am using an ever growing list of values in column A populated via the `UNIQUE()` function from another sheet.

At the moment I am manually dragging the formula down when there are more values in column A, but this is inefficient and I'm sure there must be a better option.

Ideally due to the size of the sheet id prefer if this was completed using a formula within google sheets instead of a trigger function within google scripts, if that is the only way however that could also work.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Without seeing the formulas you have in B, C, D and/or acces to  an example spreadsheet, it is hard to visualize what you try to achieve.

Comment: The formulas are vlookups, the formulas are fairly irrelevant as they can be wrapped in any function that may complete this. A sheet will be dynamically populated, via an import of a json script, the unqiue values from collumn A are then taken from this sheet using UNIQUE() on another sheet. I then have formulas in B, C, D which do a vlookup correspondant to the value in collumn A. The number of rows in collumn A will grow over time and i dont want to have to drag down the formula from B,C,D ideally id like it to be populated if there is a value in collumn A. I hope that makes more sense?

Comment: Well, it seems you need to wrap the VLOOKUP in arrayFormula then instead of doing a VLOOKUP on every separate row ?

Comment: So for example, how would this be wrapped in an array formula? 

In cell B 10568

=vlookup(A10568,'Sheet 1'!A:L,12,false)

Comment: Do you want to return only one column ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you want to do a VLOOKUP on col A (in arrayformula):

```
=arrayformula(if(len(A2:A), vlookup(A2:A,'Sheet 1'!A:L,12,false),))
```

Make sure there are no other values or formulas in the column where you use this formula.

[Example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z8Ld_8F9a-oCd8eavDXArHFAZrH2A4XmoeaZiCumA4w/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thanks for this, but im unsure as to how this would solve the issue. As collumn A is going to contain 10,000-100,000 values? I need collumns B,C,D to use the value in collum A of the corresponding row for the vlookup. i.e:

In cell B 10569 =vlookup(A10569,'Sheet 1'!A:L,12,false)
In cell B 10570 =vlookup(A10570,'Sheet 1'!A:L,12,false)

The number of rows will be ever increasing in collumn A however. Which is why I am trying to find a way of populating the formula without for example dragging the formula down each time a new row with another value is added to collumn A.

Thanks!

Comment: Then a formula like that is what you need. Consider it a normal vlookup but instead of the vlookup value in one cell, it uses the col A and looks up all the values in there, row per row. So the end result should be the same as if you dragged a simple vlookup all the way down.

Comment: I've added an example sheet, so you can see what I mean.

Comment: HI JPV, is it possible to do this with an index and match? e.g:

=arrayformula(if(len(A3:A),INDEX('SheetB'!E:E,MATCH(A3:A,'SheetB'!H:H,0))))